# CSS filter on whole page

Tags: html, css

i want to know if i can put a css filter on a whole page so that you can see the page, but it has a slightly grey filter on top and nothing can by clicked on the page because the filter is on top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved by placing an empty overlay div (`<div id="overlay"></div>`) at the bottom of your DOM, with the following style:

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

You'll need to be careful if you have declared any z-indexes. Also, the overlay div may need some JavaScript treatment in case the document height is greater than the viewport's.

Comment: do i just put it at the bottom of the DOM without a z-index? or do i put it directly between <body> tags so it covers the whole page?

Comment: z-index might be needed if there are other absolute positioned elements.

Comment: @Matthew: Bottom of DOM, before closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

HTML (put this at the bottom of the page):

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    bottom:0; 
    right:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);   
}
```

If you want to support backward browsers (IE8 and below), you'll have to readjust the code. RGBA is not supported in IE, for instance.

Comment: IE6 does not support position:fixed, for all you poor guys out there who still have to support it.

Comment: Check out the rgba() overcome, above. ;-)

Comment: @lofto Yea, I know. That's how I did it before. But I don't support IE anymore `;)`