# apply css3 filter to whole page (possibly having margin)

Tags: css, css-filters

Body element has margin, I want to apply css3 filter on whole page.
When I set filter to html element, it behaves like it was on body only.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3zzb/271/) shows the problem.

```
html { background-color: red; filter: grayscale(100%); }
body { background-color: green; margin: 50px; }
```

The question is - how do I apply grayscale css3 filter to whole page that has margins in body without adding extra overlay?

**Update:**

I am looking for universal solution working on any page with any structure. like

```
html { filter:grayscale(100%) }
```

This fails on pages with body margin. I do not know if page has body margin or padding or what is box-sizing etc.

Perhaps question should be rephrased to: **What css should I inject to make ANY page grayscale?**

Comment: Is this specific to a browser? In Chrome (v38, old but still) the grayscale appears to all including `html`.

Comment: @Harry I have chrome 45 and firefox 41. In both grays scale is only on body.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe something got fixed (or) regressed in the newer versions then.

Answer (score 1):

[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/m3zzb/272/) - maybe better to use padding rather than margin?

Comment: I thought about the same solution but in this way, he can't assign a specific padding ot body, in addition to margin, anche content is attached to boundaries

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m3zzb/275/ - without wrapping but with paddings and stretch for the whole page

Comment: Thank you for great tricks. Please see update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS filter does not seem to apply to the `<html>` element, so you either have to add an extra overlay as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809644/css-filter-on-whole-page) or if you really want to avoid the overlay, give your `<body>` element a `padding` instead `margin`.

Can someone clarify if and why the filter does not apply to the CSS properties of `<html>`? A quick Google search gave me nothing.

Comment: this is exactly my problem - why filter is not applied to html element and what are the possible workarounds

Comment: Gotcha! Can you inject CSS *and* JavaScript? In that case you could add an overlay dynamically.

Comment: I can, however overlay will not help. I do not want to cover page but change it to grayscale. It must stay as functional as it was before. Just grayscaled.

Answer (score 0):

I did wrap it on divs, not `html` and `body` but `.night-mode` and `.wrapper` and it is working 
Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/L3nozzjt/)

Comment: thank you, but I cannot change page structure, so this will not work for me.