# How to apply a filter to an entire webpage, without hiding the elements?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon

I'm making a simple Firefox web extension that allows the user to apply a filter to a webpage. When I try applying the CSS filters through `document.body.style.filter` some of the elements suddenly become hidden (on YouTube clicking full screen hides all of the elements except the title bar, idk why).

I've [looked at a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809644/css-filter-on-whole-page) and asked ChatGPT (also provided a similar solution) but it didn't seem to work on in [my implemenation](https://github.com/WriteThatDown/Fliterz-extension/blob/cd72aa88557d8a31e87f84f160bded22da574ce5/filterz/filter.js#L25). The most important part of my code is here:

```js
// Create a container element
const container = document.createElement("div");
container.style.cssText = `
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
pointer-events: none;
z-index: 9999;`;

// Append the container to the body
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', container);
```

I'm looking for a reason to why my code doesn't work, or if there was never any hope of it working in the first place, a good solution to applying a filter to an entire page without any weird artifacts (I don't have to support any old browsers btw)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to fight against whoever authored the CSS, so your results may vary. But the following will apply a filter to all elements on the page. The asterisk is a wildcard. The !important declaration is a way of forcing your style.

Try:

```
*{
   filter: blur(5px) !important;
}
```

---

Question: How to use this?

Answer: You can create a stylesheet with JavaScript and then add it to the page.

```
//Define the data
var stylesheet_data = '*{ filter: blur(5px) !important; }';

//Get the elements
var head_element = ( document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] );
var style_element = document.createElement('style');

//Configure the stylesheet element
style_element.type = 'text/css';
style_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stylesheet_data));

//Add it to the head
head_element.appendChild(style_element);
```

See also: [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

---

Additional note:
It doesn't appear that adding some type of screen element and then applying your filter to that will work.

```
<div id="screen" style="
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
/* background: black; */
z-index: 999999;
filter: grayscale(50%);
"></div>
```